# How can I get required line?

Tags: qt, qstring

I wrote code, that takes output from QProcess to QTextStream, than show line that I need:

```
QProcess p;
p.start("fdisk",QStringList() << "/dev/sdb" << "-l");
p.waitForFinished();

QString processOutput = p.readAll();
QTextStream processOutputTextStream(&processOutput);
QString line;
while(!processOutputTextStream.atEnd()){
    line = processOutputTextStream.readLine();
    if(line.contains("Disk /dev/sdb:")){
        qDebug() << line;
    }

}
```

The output:

```
"Disk /dev/sdb: 28.67 GiB, 30765219840 bytes, 60088320 sectors"
```

I need only last numbers (60088320)

How to do this?

Comment: use `auto words = line.split("");` `auto number_str = words.at(words.length() - 2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
auto words = line.split(" "); auto number_str = words.at(words.length() - 2);
```

Thanks to eyllanesc